JSON Language Server client: couldn't create connection to server
I am getting the following when I open VSCode with a Salesforce Lightening Web Components project.
I believe these errors are all related, so I am putting them in one post.

Clicking "Go to output" for the first error gives:
2024-12-06 17:45:47.112 [info] [Error - 5:45:47 PM] JSON Language Server client: couldn't create connection to server.
2024-12-06 17:45:47.112 [info] TypeError: this._getServerWorkingDir(...).then(...).finally is not a function
    at t.activate (c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\json-language-features\client\dist\node\jsonClientMain.js:1:576318)

Clicking "Go to output" for the second error gives:
[Info  - 5:45:46 PM] ESLint server is starting.
[Info  - 5:45:46 PM] ESLint server stopped.
[Error - 5:45:46 PM] ESLint client: couldn't create connection to server.
TypeError: this._getServerWorkingDir(...).then(...).finally is not a function
    at Object.MessagePortMain._internalPort.emit (node:electron/js2c/utility_init:2:2949)
[Error - 5:45:46 PM] Starting the server failed.
TypeError: this._getServerWorkingDir(...).then(...).finally is not a function
    at Object.MessagePortMain._internalPort.emit (node:electron/js2c/utility_init:2:2949)

Clicking "Go to output" for the third error gives the same output as the second error.
What would I need to change in order to resolve this problem?
